# MySQL doesn't count the last item

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using mysql to output data from my database but it will display everything but not the last column. For example if have `card1`, `card2`, `card3`, `card4` it will only give me `card1`, `card2`, `card3` but not the `card4`. If i want to get the `card4` i need to add `card5`. This happens even with ranges. For example i want `card5` to `card10` it should display 5 items but it will display only 4. Any ideas?

My query:

```
mysqli_query($con, 
"SELECT * FROM builds 
WHERE approved = 'yes' 
ORDER BY build_id 
DESC 
LIMIT 0, 10");
```

And for the ranges:

```
mysqli_query($con, 
"SELECT * FROM builds 
WHERE approved = 'yes' 
and build_price BETWEEN $price_min
AND $price_max");
```

Comment: What happens when you execute query inside mysql?

Comment: Could you show us some table data?

Comment: If i run the quary it does return all the results corectly

Comment: It seems to be php's problem

Comment: Can you show us the php code that uses the result of your `mysqli_query` call?

Comment: Technically, the queries are all ok, and such a problem seems a bit weird. Maybe its on how you're displaying data after executing the mysql. Post more details!

Comment: Its a while loop. I cant post it here because its too long. Take a pastebin instead: http://pastebin.com/b8KsbZ2Y

Comment: @MeletisFlevarakis You solved your problem already?

Comment: @divaka yep! the problem was in the fetch. it should be after the while loop. not before!